# textAlignment wont work with supportsRtl false

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created buttons that look as follows:

[image]

The xml code for it is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_whishlist"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_whishlist"
                android:text="Whishlist"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvWhishlistBooksCount"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWhishlistBooksCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="0"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_whishlist"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_whishlist" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Everything worked great however for some reason the text inside the button stopped appearing at the start and it always shows it in the middle.

Is there any way to fix it so It will appear again next to the heart shape/message icon?

**EDIT:**

I found that when I change my manifest to `android:supportsRtl="true"` it works.
However, I do want it to be `android:supportsRtl="false"` so I need to overcome it somehow.

Thank you.

Comment: TextView has android:gravity="center". Try by removing this property.

Comment: didnt work mate

Comment: Did you try with  android:textAlignment="viewStart" . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment

Comment: now I tried, it's just stuck there in the middle =[

Comment: Probably you can try giving a bit of padding . Something like this android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_whishlist"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_whishlist"
        android:text="Whishlist"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
        android:textAlignment="textStart" \\ remove this line 
        android:gravity="start"            \\ add this line
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvWhishlistBooksCount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: android:gravity="start|center_vertical" did the work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you set `android:supportsRtl` to `false` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file make sure that you are not using attributes like `layoutDirection` or `textAlignment` that force RTL layout.

If you want to use `textAlignment` there are two way by this you can archive this:

1. The activity where you want to enforce left-to-right (LTR) layout, add the following code to the `onCreate` method or another appropriate location:

```kotlin
 // Inside your activity's onCreate method or an appropriate location
    val view: View = window.decorView
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
         view.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
     }
```

2. Another approach by specifying the layout direction in your app's theme. This method will set the layout direction to LTR for the entire app

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Other theme attributes -->
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
</style>
```